# which branch will get the codes that I have pushed, if I branched from an existing branch?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

let's say we have an existing branch named

```
stable-branch
```

then I branched from that branch by

```
git checkout -b mybranch stable-branch
```

after I'm done coding..if I

```
git commit -m "blah blah blah"
```

and then

```
git push origin mybranch
```

will the stable-branch remote repository get affected after I pushed it to my own branch ?

Comment: No, since you're specifying pushing to `origin/mybranch`. You would need to push to `stable-branch` to affect its remote repo.

Comment: you're the first one to answer. to be fair. please put your answer to the proper input box if you want your answer to get accepted. thanks

Comment: Simple yes/no answers generally don't warrant a formal answer, so no worries here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
Your code/commit can be seen under `mybranch` **only** in remote too.

And the best way is :

```
git fetch origin // (or your repo name)
git checkout -b myNewBranch
git reset --hard origin/stable-branch
Do changes
git status // to see changed files
git commit -am "commit message here"
git branch // to see branches in your local repo
git log --oneline -20 // to see your new commit in the list
git fetch origin // Fetch again (to get new commits if any)
git rebase origin/stable-branch // Rebase again to make sure your's is the latest one
git push origin myNewBranch
```

Here you dont have to checkout your stable-branch if you don't have any change in it.

Answer (score 0):

The repository containing the two branches will be affected and from now on contains the changes you pushed on the branch `mybranch`. BUT: `stable-branch` will not see any of that changes. This is the very concept of branching.

You work on `mybranch`, you commit and push at will and by so are able to collaborate with your team on the feature your are developing. By pushing the local feature branch becomes remote and visible to all other developers on the repository. The stable release branch remains the same (it must do so, otherwise you would always be developing on a potentially producing branch. Big no no...).

`stable-branch` will be affected as soon as you merge `mybranch` to it and push afterwards in a process like

```
git checkout mybranch
git commit -m "stuff"
git push -u origin mybranch //optional publishing
git checkout stable-branch
git merge mybranch //now affecting stable-branch for the first time
//optionally solve occurring merge-conflicts now
git push -u origin stable-branch
```

If you are working alone all publishing before merging is optional but recommended as this tracks your version history remotely (basically what Git is made for) and by so allows rollbacks, rebases and working on different machines.

See [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) for a detailed manual.